# Cordova Media Capture - Recording and Playing Audio

Tags: cordova, audio, audio-recording, phonegap

Noob here so please bear with me - I'm trying to use Cordova media capture for audio recording in my webapp (using Appery). I've used the code on the documentation and tested it on an iPad - the native recording software pops up when I record, but once I'm done - how do I play back the recording?

I would simply like the users to be able to hit "play" in a div somewhere to replay that recording. This seems like it's something painfully obvious and easy, but I've been stuck on it for 2 weeks! If you could help it would really make my day, please help!!!

This is one of the variation of code I've tried, but it didn't work:

```
**// capture callback
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;

    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        // do something interesting with the file

        $('#A').append('<div class="list-group-item"><audio><source  src="'+mediaFiles[i].fullPath+'"</audio>play</div>');
    }
};**
```